# Hybrid Web/Desktop app - Ruby on Rails or Django on Python?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, linux

I am going to write a hybrid Web/Desktop app.
The main purpose of the app is to be something like a daemon, running on a Linux machine. But it should also provide a rich interface via web for doing configuration, reporting and management.

I have two things in mind for doing this:

- Ruby on Rails
- Django with Python

I have a fair knowledge of Python, but I know nothing of Ruby, but I have plenty of time, so I can learn Ruby if needed.

For the frameworks, I know some Django, but again no Rails.

Which one do you think I should go with, considering that I have plenty of time to learn and also, the benefits of the framework itself, for later projects.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails or Django? (or something else?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91846/rails-or-django-or-something-else)

Comment: this has been asked numerous times.

Comment: @pastylegs What makes this post different, is that it's a Hybrid application, not a regular Web one.

Comment: Personally, I don't see how it is different. Django and Rails basically do the same thing.

Comment: Check out [pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/).

Comment: @Ash Yes, they do the same thing for the web interface. But how about the Desktop part? Are Python and Ruby the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do neither. Use an event subsystem such as Twisted, glib, Qt, etc. and have it act as both a GUI mainloop and a web server.

Comment: Can you give me more detail please?

Comment: Not sure which details you need here. Web servers use a loop. Desktop apps use a loop. Make them the same loop.

Comment: Twisted looks promising. I will go for it. Thanks Matt.